# Azure Access control (IAM) roles - Reader vs Resource specific Reader

Tags: azure

I can see it very clear from documentation, so asking this here does Azure IAM Reader role includes all that resource type specific Reader role or not exactly? For example if I take some resource, like Log Analytics Workspace - there I can assign both Reader and Log Analytics Workspace Reader, roles descriptions provided by documentation/Azure portal UI are the following:

**Reader** - The Reader role allows you to view all the resources in an Automation account but can't make any changes.

**Log Analytics Reader** - The Log Analytics Reader role allows you to view and search all monitoring data as well as view monitoring settings. This includes viewing the configuration of Azure diagnostics on all Azure resources.

By looking at those descriptions it is not super clear as whether I can consider Log Analytics Reader as narrower role/subset of what Reader role assignment gives me when it comes to Log Analytics workspace permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role definitions for each built-in role will help you identify exactly which role you want based on which component permissions it provides.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#log-analytics-reader

Comment: That helps a little bit, so Reader = */read, Data Analytics Reader = */read, Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/analytics/query/action, Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/search/action so if I read this correctly Data Analytics Reader is broader has more permissions and it seems if I grant Data Analytics Reader it also includes all the things plain Reader can do.